How to export csv data in table format with merged cells, in laravel
I've to export data in csv format in laravel. The way i'm using is exporting the file only with rows but i want to format this as shared in the image the format i want to export the csv
I'm sharing the controller function and export file here
file name App\Exports\ExportCertificate.php
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\Certificates;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use DB;

class ExportCertificate implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        // Define the header row with the names of the database fields
        return [
            'Sr.No.',
            'Batch Number',
            'Batch Number Manual',
            'Exporter Name',
            'Certificate Number',
            'Certificate Date',
            'Item Name',
            'Treated QTY',
            'Invoice Number',
            'Invoice Date',
            'Country Of Export',
            'Moisture Before Treat',
            'Moisture After Treat',
            'Total Time',
            'Warmup Time',
            'Dwell Time',
            'Company Name',
            // Add more columns as needed
        ];
    }
    public function collection()
    {
        $added_by           = session('login_type');
        $added_by_id        = session('user_id');

        $Records            = Certificates::where('added_by',$added_by)
                                ->where('added_by_id',$added_by_id)
                                ->where('id',$this->id)
                                //->orderBy('id','DESC')
                                ->get();

        return $Records->map(function ($Record, $index) {

                $BatchDetails   = \App\Models\Batches::find($Record->batch_id);
                $exporters      = \App\Models\Exporterlist::find($Record->exporter_id);
                $Item       = DB::table('items')->where('id',$Record->item_id)->first();
                
                if(isset($BatchDetails->manual_batch_number))
                {
                    $manual_batch_number = $BatchDetails->manual_batch_number;
                }
                else
                {
                    $manual_batch_number = 'N/A';
                }

                if(isset($exporters->party_name))
                {
                    $exporterName = $exporters->party_name;
                }
                else
                {
                    $exporterName = 'N/A';
                }

                if(isset($Item->name))
                {
                    $ItemName = $Item->name;
                }
                else
                {
                    $ItemName = 'N/A';
                }



                return [
                    'Sr.No.'                => $index + 1,
                    'Batch Number'          => $Record->batch_id ?? 'N/A',
                    'Batch Number Manual'   => $manual_batch_number, 
                    'Exporter Name'         => $exporterName, 
                    'Certificate Number'    => $Record->certificate_number ?? 'N/A',
                    'Certificate Date'      => $Record->certificate_date ?? 'N/A',
                    'Item Name'             => $ItemName,
                    'Treated QTY'           => $Record->treated_quantity,
                    'Invoice Number'        => $Record->invoice_number,
                    'Invoice Date'          => $Record->invoice_date,
                    'Country Of Export'     => $Record->country_of_export,
                    'Moisture Before Treat' => $Record->before_moisture,
                    'Moisture After Treat'  => $Record->after_moisture,
                    'Total Time'            => $Record->total_time,
                    'Warmup Time'           => $Record->warmup_time,
                    'Dwell Time'            => $Record->dwell_time,
                    'Company Name'          => $Record->company_name,
                    // Add more columns as needed
                ];
            });
    }
}


and below is the function of controller in App\Http\Controllers\admin\CertificateController.php
    public function export_certificates_excel ($id)
    {
        return Excel::download(new ExportCertificate($id), 'certificates.xlsx');
    }

and this is the route
Route::any('/export_certificates_excel/{id}', 'CertificateController@export_certificates_excel')->name('certificate.export_certificates_excel');


in order to implement your custom headings format, your export needs to implement the WithEvents interface:
class ExportCertificate implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithEvents
{
  ...
  
  public function registerEvents(): array
  {
    return [
      BeforeSheet::class => function (BeforeSheet $event) {
        $event->sheet->getDelegate()->setCellValue('B1', 'Your custom heading');
        ...
        // other headings

        // merge cells
        $event->sheet->getDelegate()->setMergeCells(['A4:M4', 'A5:H5', ...]);
      }];
  }
}

via the setCellValue you can fill your empty heading cells, and via setMergeCells you can pass a list of cells to merge in "$from:$to" format. Keeps in mind to start the data after your heading rows.
